# Python entry point commandline script not found when installing with --user flag

Tags: python, installation, setuptools, entry-point

I recently wrote a package which comes with a command line tool. The setup.py looks something like this

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(...
      entry_points = {
            'console_scripts': [
                    'cmdname = modulename.binary:main',
                ],
          },
      ...)
```

everything is fine when I install it without the --user flag via

```
$ sudo python setup.py install
$ cmdname
Yes, I'm here! Give me a command!
```

however, installing it without root access gives

```
$ python setup.py install --user
$ cmdname
-bash: cmdname: command not found
```

I guess there should be a directory where user scripts are linked to that should be exported to the PATH? How can I achieve that setuptools links to the entry point anyway? Or is that not possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The binary was installed to `~/.local/bin/`. Hence, adding `export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH` to `~/.bash_profile` and

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

solved the issue.

Comment: Man! No one could give me a proper answer! After an hour of searching you saved me from my misery! Thanks!